# Angular Bootstrap Accordion and ngAnimate, how to prevent animation on initial page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-animate, angular-bootstrap

### Setup and problem:

I'm using Angular, angular-bootstrap, angular-animate, and angular-ui-router and I want a simple accordion. Getting the accordion to work and animating is simple enough, but I want to prevent the animation from happening during the initial page load. I noticed that this problem does not occur in the [angular-bootstrap demos](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion), so I suspect that angular-ui-router or something else might be interfering, but I'm totally stumped. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

### Relevant markup in my template

```html
<uib-accordion>
    <uib-accordion-group heading="1" is-open="true">
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
    </uib-accordion-group>
    <uib-accordion-group heading="2">
        content
    </uib-accordion-group>
    <uib-accordion-group heading="3">
        content
    </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

### JS, showing my angular-ui-router setup (might not be relevant)

```js
(function(){
var app = angular.module("mapc-workshop", ["ui.router", "ui.bootstrap", "ngAnimate"]);

app.factory('workshopModel', ['$http', function($http){
    var workshopStuff = $http.get("data/workshop_activities.json").then(function (resp) {
        return resp.data;
    });

    var factory = {};
    factory.all = function(){
        return workshopStuff;
    }
    return factory;
}]);

app.config( function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $stateProvider
        .state("workshop", {
            url: "/workshop/{section}/{subsection}/{activity}",
            templateUrl: "assets/js/app/templates/workshop_home.html",
            params: { 
                section: {value: null, squash: true}, 
                subsection: {value: null, squash: true},
                activity: {value: null, squash: true}
            },
            resolve: {
                workshop_data: ['workshopModel',
                    function( workshopModel){
                        return workshopModel.all();
                    }]
            },
            controller: "WorkshopController"


        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/workshop/');

});
}());
```

### Notes

- I'm not doing anything related to transitions or animations in my CSS
- I have tried to remove any ng-show or ng-repeat to eliminate them as possible culprits.
- I'm not doing anything in my controller that has anything to do with the accordion or animations.
- I'm also not able to find where the animation/transitions are being added when I look in the chrome inspector.

Thanks for taking a look, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you remove ` is-open="true">` from your code? Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald If I remove is-open="true", then every accordion group will start out closed, and remain closed. I'm hoping for one of them to be open on page load, but without seeing the animation of it opening.

Answer (score 0):

Animation does appear on [angular-bootstrap demos](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion), only very fast.

The simplest way to avoid showing the animation on page load would be to hide it until the accordion is already rendered and animated.

Something like:

```
<uib-accordion ng-show="pageLoaded">
```

And in the controller:

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.pageLoaded = true;  
  }, 100);
```

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/751vSVKq6PE4V8qC0t7r?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Daniel! You might be right, but if you go to the demo you linked, you'll notice that the first time it loads, it 'snaps' open, even without the $timout suggestion. However, in my project, you see the full opening animation, which I'd like to avoid. Is there perhaps some css class I should be overwriting to make the initial entry animation last for 0s? I tried overwrite .ng-animate, .ng-enter, and maybe a few others, but nothing seems to ever be applied.